# How to check function input is a list of list?

Tags: python, list, types, type-hinting

I want to make sure the function input is in the following format: `[[s1, e1], [s2, e2], ...]`, where `s1, e1, ...` are either `int` or `float` type. I wonder how can I assert the input variable is in this format?

I have looked into `typing` module in Python, but it seems type hint doesn't enforce anything except functioning as a "hint". I can use `isinstance()` to check if the input is a list, but is there a convenient way to check if the input follows strictly as the format I specified above? Thank you for any comment or answer in advance.

Comment: Use `mypy` along with type annotations and then you can statically check your type annotations (i.e. before you even run the code) to make sure that the code matches the declared types.  It requires a bit of discipline to use annotations/mypy consistently, but once you get used to it, it it's *significantly* less work than doing lots of runtime checks, and much more likely to help you catch bugs early.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
f = [[1],[2],[3]]

def func(l):
    if isinstance(f,list):
        if all(isinstance(a,list) for a in f) and all(isinstance(ele,float) or isinstance(ele,int) for list_ in l for ele in list_):
            return True
    return False

def your_func(input_:list):
    if func(input_):
        #do_something or write you code.
        pass
```

Comment: btw `isinstance(x, t1) or isinstance(x, t2)` can be shortened to `isinstance(x, (t1, t2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(arr):
    for i, el in enumerate(arr):
        assert isinstance(el, list), f"item {i} is not a list"
        assert len(el) == 2, f"item {i} has wrong number of elements"
        for n in el:
            assert isinstance(n, (float, int)), f"item {i} has wrong type of element"
            
foo([[1, 2], [3.1, 4.1], [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

```
mylist = [[1,2],[1,3.112],[1, 1]]

if all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), mylist)):
    print("list of lists")

if all(all(isinstance(ele, float) or isinstance(ele, int) for ele in item) for item in mylist):
    print("all numbers")
```

Comment: I thinks `isinstance(ele, (float, int))` works

Comment: Or this union way in Python 3.10+ `isinstance(elem, float | int)`